# NSLookup Has Stopped Working (Won't Start)

Tags: windows-10, wireshark, nslookup

NSLookup on Windows 10 x64 (10.0.14393) cannot be started anymore. Earlier today, I would be greeted by the prompt after running `nslookup` from CMD. Now, I am greeted with this screen:

[image: NSLookup error message]

The program only runs when I specify `-?`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup -?
Usage:
   nslookup [-opt ...]             # interactive mode using default server
   nslookup [-opt ...] - server    # interactive mode using 'server'
   nslookup [-opt ...] host        # just look up 'host' using default server
   nslookup [-opt ...] host server # just look up 'host' using 'server'
```

The only change I can recall making since this morning, when the command worked, is the installation of three programs related to a networking course I am taking.

1. Wireshark 2.2.3
2. WinPcap 4.1.3
3. UsbPcap 1.0.0.7

Things I have tried:

1. Offline checkdisk of all partitions (no errors)
2. Online system file checker (no violations found)
3. Uninstalled all software that I installed today, one at a time, and rebooted after each
4. Cleared DNS cache
5. Directly specify command and server with switches

Is there some kind of cache I can't find? I'm out of ideas.

**Edits by request:**

Minidump file: http://bitfracture.com/downloads/temp/nslookup.exe.8668.dmp

Full dump file: http://bitfracture.com/downloads/temp/nslookup.exe.548.dmp

Comment: generate a crashdump and share (onedrive, dropbox) it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have generated the dump file and appended it to my original question. Thank you.

Comment: this is a minidump. Change the value **DumpType** to 2 to generate a full dump

Comment: I have added the full dump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently sorting this out, but it appears to be that Something is re-writing the following REG_SZ registry key into a REG_BINARY key, and it causes NSLOOKUP to choke as a result

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters SearchList registry value

Delete the REG_BINARY or change back to a REG_SZ and the problem goes away

We're pursuing it as a problem with F5 VPN (12x upgrade), but as I said it's still under investigation

Faulting application name: nslookup.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0xe86915da

Faulting module name: nslookup.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0xe86915da

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x0000000000009abc

Faulting process id: 0x4170

Faulting application start time: 0x01d3d5a05a312c37

Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\nslookup.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\nslookup.exe

Report Id: f0e23fc2-dfb6-4152-b566-b1b7b05bca29

====================================================

Got two additional PC’s today, and believe I found what causes this (and it’s not F5 DNS RELAY SERVICE – although restarting the service on an impacted PC will write the bad key too).

The missing piece of the pie is that you have to be logged in as an “Admin” (a -A or user with Admin rights) for things to work as seen below, you aren’t an admin and the whole thing doesn’t break, but below as an admin is a reliable repro, I did it on two PC’s.

1. I got a freshly built Windows 10 PC
2. Login as my -A (admin)
3. NOTE that the PC will not have
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
               SearchList
               SearchList_F5_BACKUP_VALUE
4. It will have the this VPN: 7103.2015.811.317 (11.5.3)
5. Launch that VPN and ACCEPT any UAC prompts
6. Enter your VPN credentials
7. When VPN fully launches it will write these keys (as REG_SZ)
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
   "SearchList_F5_BACKUP_VALUE"=""
   "SearchList"="ad.allstate.com,allstate.com"
8. Exit VPN (disconnect then exit from the system tray) and it will blank the SearchList value (leaving it a REG_SZ with no value), and then delete the SearchList_F5_BACKUP_VALUE entry
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
   "SearchList"=""
   "SearchList_F5_BACKUP_VALUE"="" (deleted entirely)
9. Install 12.1.3 VPN
10. The install of 12.1.3 will change the SearchList value from a REG_SZ to a REG_BINARY (BAD)
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
    "SearchList"=hex:
11. The REG_BINARY value causes nslookup to crash

The writing (and value blanking) of the initial keys (which only happens if you are logged in as an admin, and yes any UAC prompts when launching VPN) is a process included in the 11.5.3 VPN product - C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\F5ElHelper.exe – version 7103, 2015, 0811, 0317

The changing of format of the SearchList key (which happens if the SearchList key existed due to the previous) is performed during VPN 12.1.3 install by a 12.1.3 VPN product - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F5FltSrv.exe – version 7133, 2018, 0112, 2028

Comment: This is a working solution on all of my Windows 10 systems that encountered the problem, and an F5 VPN was present on all of them.

Comment: I had a similar problem with all DNS (including nslookup) failing on Windows 10 / Microsoft Surface Pro.  The `SearchList` value was indeed a `REG_BINARY`, I deleted it and DNS worked again.  There was no F5 or VPN installed; the problem seemed to be triggered by a Windows Update.

Comment: Wow thanks for this answer... this was driving me insane. May I ask how you even figured this out? Also after upgrading to windows 10 20H2 - the registery key was re-written, even though the latest F5 BigEdge was installed. Seems like something triggers during a windows update that also causes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I [asked Andrew Richards](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/) and he told me that is is a known bug, that is already logged in their bug tracker, but looking at the telemetry shows, that only a few users run into it.

So, this issue has a low priority for Microsoft. So use [Powershell commands which do the same](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/08/replace-nslookup-with-a-built-in-windows-8-powershell-function/).

Answer (score 0):

If un installing the application is not helping you fix the issue then try to recover the PC to pervious recovery point available. normal system used to schedule a  backup before it's going to install and critical app.

Note : Before try for older recovery point restore. Try in event Viewer for any errors. It might help you to find the trace of issue a\

Comment: Event log (error): `Faulting application name: nslookup.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899977. 
Faulting module name: nslookup.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899977. 
Exception code: 0xc0000005. 
Fault offset: 0x0000000000009c8c. 
Faulting process id: 0x878. 
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2706c879e2a7b. 
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\nslookup.exe. 
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\nslookup.exe. 
Report Id: b734da9e-b67c-48cd-8948-087857e9fe09. 
Faulting package full name: . 
Faulting package-relative application ID: `

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any recovery points I can reverse to. I'm running on a small solid state drive. If there isn't a fix, I may just end up reinstalling my OS eventually.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue and it appears the service "F5FltSrv.exe" incorrectly writes SearchList as REG_BINARY.  The service grabs the values from "SearchList_F5_BACKUP_VALUE" after a restart of the service or a reboot(20h2 feature update).  It should write it back as REG_SZ but the service doesn't check the length of the string, including the terminating null character.

Microsoft put a Safeguard hold on systems with F5 VPN installed.
ID - 33324334

## Matching GatedBlock....FOUND!
GatedBlock:

Name             Value                                  Ordinal

---

SdbAppraiserData GatedBlock                             2
SdbAppName       F5 VPN                                 2
SdbEntryGuid     {5d7fe093-4241-4d64-b591-3b65998df294} 2
SdbAppGuid       {6de72de3-37e5-4ef3-a3b5-0cdc4dcba221} 2

I used the PowerShell module FU.WhyAmIBlocked to grab this information.